# Trying to convert a Windows Runtime command to be Mac compatible

Tags: java

How can I create a function to run the terminal commands "./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace" and "./gradlew eclipse" using the Runtime Class? I'm having a hard time running terminal or getting any terminal commands to work.

```
private static void runGradleSetup(File minecraftFolder){
    String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");
    System.out.println("Operating System: " + operatingSystem);
    if(operatingSystem.contains("Windows")) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try{
            System.out.println("STARTING SETUP... -close windows after completion");
            Process workspaceSetup = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start /wait gradlew setupDecompWorkspace", null, minecraftFolder);
            System.out.println("Starting Workspace Setup...");
            workspaceSetup.waitFor();
            Process eclipseSetup = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start /wait gradlew eclipse", null, minecraftFolder);
            System.out.println("Starting Eclipse Setup...");
            eclipseSetup.waitFor();
            System.out.println("... SETUP COMPLETE");
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Error: Interrupted Exception");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: IOException Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Those are strictly Windows commands; Mac doesn't have `cmd.exe`, and the version of `gradlew` that is being started is clearly for that OS. Unless you can find a Mac version of the application, these command can't be converted.

Comment: "./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace" and "./gradlew eclipse" are the Mac commands for the program, the code above contains the Windows command. I was hoping Mac would have their own version or way of accessing their "cmd.exe"... I read something about "bin/bash" but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to go from there.